# What's the point of using "new" when creating a new instance of a class or datatype in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and programming as whole and I would like to know what is the main reason to use the "new" keyword specifically to create a new instance of a class or datatype since I can simply create one by not using "new". Do forgive my naivety and some help is appreciated.

Just for an example, I can create a new instance of a random user-made class "myClass" by saying

```
myClass newClass;
```

So, why to use this -

```
myClass newClass = new myClass();
```

Comment: using new calls the constructor of the class.

Comment: `myClass newClass` simply declares that `newClass` is of type `myClass`.  It doesn't create anything - if you try to reference it you will get a null reference exception.

Comment: @mpacheco: I think you should specify what you mean by "the basics of Object-oriented programming". Without any further info, I would associate that with the keywords *classes vs. instances + inheritance and polymorphism*. Variables being references that can become `null` are not inherent to OOP as such, even though they are quite central to C#, and some related languages, in particular.

Comment: Keep in mind that this subject is different between C# and C++ (in case you already know C++). In C++, your syntax creates an instance with automatic storage semantics. In C#, your syntax simply creates an uninitialized reference variable. In C++, `new` creates an instance with manual storage semantics. In C#, all class instances are created using `new` and there is no applicable distinction (because all instances are GC-managed by default).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: In C#, this syntax declares a variable and doesn't initialize it to anything. Attempting to use it before it's assigned will yield a compiler error.

Comment: `new` allocates memory needed to create an instance of that class. If your class is just a collection of static methods and fields, then I suppose you wouldn't need `new`.

Comment: @JeffBridgman: But in that case, the variable would be unnecessary in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

By writing

```
myClass newClass;
```

, you do *not* create a new instance of `myClass`. You just create a *variable* that *can point* to such an instance, but you do not assign a value.

Try to access one of the methods or fields of `myClass`:

- If `newClass` was declared outside of a method (i.e. as a field), a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be thrown, because `newClass` is not pointing to any instance of `myClass`.
- If `newClass` was declared within a method (i.e. as a local variable), the code will not even compile because the compiler will state that `myClass` is uninitialized.

Comment: If you try to access one of the methods or fields of `myClass`, the program will not compile since `myClass` hasn't been assigned to. Only fields receive default values in C#.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: True, if `myClass` is declared as a local variable. I have made that clearer in my answer now, thanks.